# Can XDG_CACHE_HOME be cleared on every reboot?

Tags: linux

I would like to keep `XDG_CACHE_HOME` (by default `$HOME/.cache`) on a `tmpfs` mount. That means data doesn't survive between reboots. According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory) `XDG_CACHE_HOME` is equivalent to `/var/cache` which means that theoretically this directory content can be safely discarded.

So my question is whether I am missing something when I assume it may be a good idea keeping `XDG_CACHE_HOME` in `RAM`.

Comment: look in your cache folder, under var/cache exists more as only your homestuff, as ususally programm saving there persisting things like nginx which keeps its cache there or apt - or or or, in my mind in case you delete any subfolder on var/cache your programs might not more starting

Comment: Other than all your GUI programs suddenly getting a lot slower?